# Duplication of titles, Magento Forgotten password page TITLE

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

By default non-cms pages have the same title of the website itself, and I have a seomoz account which reports me that I have 2 pages with the same title

http://www.theprinterdepo.com/contacts/
http://www.theprinterdepo.com/customer/account/forgotpassword/

I really need to change the title of those 2 pages and in Magento is kind of complicated because I suppose its on some XML files.

The problem is that I dont know in which one.

I have created this file:
/home/theprint/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/MAG060062/layout/local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<contacts_index_index translate="label">
        <label>Contact Us Form</label>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
        </reference>
    </contacts_index_index>
    <customer_account_forgotpassword translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Forgot Your Password</title></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_forgotpassword>
</layout>
</xml>
```

However its not working

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your app/design/frontend/[interface]/[theme]/layout/local.xml, add:

```
    <contacts_index_index translate="label">
        <label>Contact Us Form</label>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
        </reference>
    </contacts_index_index>
    <customer_account_forgotpassword translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Forgot Your Password</title></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_forgotpassword>
```

Comment: the actual path of the file is app/design/frontend/[interface]/[theme]/layout/local.xml

Comment: that file does not exist! I dont even  have a design folder on the root of the site. I searched for local.xml file and the only one I found is where the mysql user and passwords are on /app/etc/local/

Comment: that file does not exist there, I suppose I can just create it

Comment: @Locaaaaa you have to create that file, that's where you'll put all your specifics layout updates

Comment: just wrap the code above into <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0"> .. </layout>

Comment: @Locaaaaa the final `</xml>` tag shouldn't be there, delete it.